# Are non-ascii characters allowed as values for email X-headers?

Tags: email

I'm troubleshooting an issue that seems related to a mail server not being able to understand some international characters in the value of an x-header. This leads to a broader question: are non-ascii characters permitted as x-header values?

Answer (score 2):

Non-ASCII characters are not permitted in MIME headers.

While X-header fields were explicitly protected from being standardised, they must conform to the general MIME header standards. [RFC822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822) (section 3.1.1) defines the header fields as:

> Each header field can be viewed as a single, logical line of ASCII  characters,  comprising a field-name and a field-body.

[RFC2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047) (Message Header Extensions for Non-ASCII Text) defines the methods for encoding non-ASCII characters.

Comment: …and [RFC6152](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6152) defines the transport of full 8-bit data (including UTF-8) in headers and body. Do note also that RFC822 (dated 1982) has been marked as "obsoleted by" [RFC2822](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822) in 2001, which _also_ has been marked as "obsoleted by" [RFC5322](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322) in 2008, so it's no longer an authoritative reference of any sort.

Comment: Does RFC6152 really apply to header fields?